# People API returns no connections when authenticating via Service Account

Tags: python, google-api, google-people-api

I'm trying to get the most basic bare-bones example of using the People API, but I'm having some difficulty.

I'm using python to retrieve a list of all my connections using the People V1 API. Importantly, I'm using a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#formingclaimset) since the script I'm writing will run on a server and can not use the traditional 3-legged OAuth that involves a user action.

In my developer console, I have service account credentials set up.

[image]

I also have the People API enabled.

[image]

I downloaded the secret JSON credentials as well (redacted for obvious reasons)

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": [REDACTED],
  "private_key_id": [REDACTED],
  "private_key": [REDACTED],
  "client_email": [REDACTED],
  "client_id": [REDACTED],
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": [REDACTED]
}
```

And finally, my script. I used a simplified version lifted from [this example](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/python) provided by Google. The main difference here is I'm using a service account so I cut out most of the method that checks for credentials and starts a user OAuth flow.

```
import httplib2

from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly'

def main():
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        'keep-in-touch-5d3ebc885d4c.json', SCOPES)

    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

    service = discovery.build('people', 'v1', http=http,
        discoveryServiceUrl='https://people.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest')

    print('List 10 connection names')
    results = service.people().connections().list(resourceName='people/me',
        pageSize=10).execute()
    connections = results.get('connections', [])

    for person in connections:
        names = person.get('names', [])
        if len(names) > 0:
            name = names[0].get('displayName')
            print(name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The problem is, this returns nothing. I know my Google+ account has at least one connection, but it's returning an empty array of results. Is there something wrong with the code itself? Or could the issue be with my account?

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this:
https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/getBatchGet You can use 'Try it!' before trying it from code.

Comment: Almost certainly a service account can't read contacts; that's private information only available to *your* account. Authenticating as an individual account to read private information can only be done with an OAuth flow, where that individual is asked to grant the access. `people/me` is certainly not *your* account; a service account is a different entity.